# Eligibility for PhD in the USA

Tags: phd, international-students

(Note: For international students)

If someone has a gap of more than 5 years after obtaining a masters degree, are they eligible for a PhD in the USA?

Comment: I don't think there is any such restrictions...

Comment: The edit changed it from 3 years to 5. The answers are still valid, I think. But the "productivity" in the meantime might be considered. But in general, in the US, lots of people who "always wanted" to do a PhD end up doing so late in life. My university had a number of such students. But if you apply you will get better information and feedback on your particular situation.

Comment: Actually i was confused that  some certain age restriction may be there..  so i edit agains ...now got its   thanks u sir @Buffy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no restriction that a PhD should be done right after a Master's degree.

For instance, I knew a returning PhD student of age >50 at a major US university.

Depending on what the candidate did in the three years in between, snatching a precious place in a PhD program may be either more difficult or easier.

Answer (score 6):

Edit: I didn't exactly answer the question before.  The short answer is that there is no such eligibility requirement.  Long, original answer below.

As with any job application, a gap is only as bad as you describe it.  You can "sell" yourself effectively by describing that gap as positively as possible-- whether you were working professionally, raising a kid, traveling, helping out your family, etc.  And quite often, the life experience you gain by having a break from schooling is a huge asset when you enter a grueling graduate program.

I don't have data to back it up ([this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-average-age-of-PhD-graduates-by-discipline) is close enough), but my perception is that the average age of PhD students in the U.S. has gone up over the past few decades, because people often need to work a "real" job, save up money, and pay off loans before taking on the job of an underpaid grad student with excessive hours.  So three years between a masters and PhD seems about right.